# Measuring an object in a photograph

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I'm trying to work out how to measure an object in a photograph. I want to measure the actual, real-world size of it. Luckily, this object has a scale in cm. My thinking is that I measure the pixels in the scale, and use that to then determine the size of the other object/s in the photo. I've been working on this in scikit images with mixed results.  One of the issues I get is that the resolution of the image changes the measurement. So, it seems that thresholding for the scale and extracting pixel counts does not work.

I know that OpenCV has the ability to measure objects with a bounding box, however the objects I'm trying to measure have uneven sides/edges, and this needs to be accounted for (the shape of the object is important too, and I can capture that using thresholding and contours).

I'm hoping that people on this board can point me in alternate/better directions for trying to solve this issue. Perhaps my approach is all wrong. Thank you.

Example photo of vase with 10 cm scale. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK2BZ.jpg)

Comment: please provide example pictures

Comment: I’ve edited my original comment to include a picture. Thanks!

Comment: from that angle you can only measure the width. imagine a plane parallel to the image plane, intersecting the object. your vase would get an inclined plane intersecting it. you can measure on that plane. everything not on that plane would be assumed to be on that plane. that means the top and bottom of the vase, not sitting on that inclined plane, get projected on that plane. the length you'd measure would be shorter than the true length. you need a top-down or a frontal view, relative to the object.

Comment: basically yes, you take the scale as a reference to figure what true length corresponds to a pixel. *detecting* the scale is another matter. scales can have arbitrary appearance. you want a high resolution picture that hasn't been compressed to bits. thresholding is probably a good approach since this scale has nice contrast.